# React Native Roles Check Requires Logout Everytime

Tags: react-native

I have built a profile tabs in react native, each tab has some checks based on the user roles, if I change the user role from my Laravel API, I have to ask the user to logout and login again, which is annoying.

Any idea what is the best approach to fix this?

Below is an example of how I save the token:

```
export const saveToken = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", value);
    setConfiguration("token", value);
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

This is how I save the login data:

```
export const saveLoginData = async (value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("userData", jsonValue);
    setConfiguration("id", value.id);
    setConfiguration("name", value.name);
    setConfiguration("email", value.email);
    setConfiguration("profile", value.profile_photo_url);
    setConfiguration("mainProfile", value.image);
    setConfiguration("mobile", value?.phone_number);
    setConfiguration("location", value?.location);
    setConfiguration("role", value?.role_id);
    setConfiguration("company", value?.company_name);
    setConfiguration("available_spin", value?.available_spin);
    setConfiguration("phone_verified", value?.phone_verified)
    setConfiguration("gender", value?.gender)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    // saving error
  }
};
```

Below is an example of how I check the roles:

```
{(role === 2 || role === 3 || role === 4 || role === 5) && (
  <ProfileCategory
    text="Citizens Discounts"
    rightIcon={true}
    icon={
      <Icon
        name="gift"
        size={25}
        color={theme == "dark" ? "white" : COLORS.gray}
      />
    }
    onPress={() => {
      if (getConfiguration("phone_verified") == 0) {
        return;
      }
      navigation.navigate("CitizensDiscounts");
    }}
  />
)}
```